# OpenCV float vs double in non image basic structures

Tags: opencv, floating-point

I understand why one may choose to use floats over doubles in a large image in OpenCV as it reduces the memory required by the image. But is there a reason to prefer float over double for other OpenCV objects such as camera matrices, rotation matrices, translation vectors, and 2D/3D points?

I understand that OpenCV tends to complain of you try to perform math with matrices and vectors that are of different type (e.g. performing math that involves pixel values of a float image and its corresponding location in the image represented with a double OpenCV structure) Is this where the (apparent to me) motivation to use float for everything comes from?

Answer (score 1):

You can get *significantly* faster computation on `float` than `double` under certain circumstances:

1) If your hardware does not support `double`, but does support `float` (some microcontrollers, some GPGPUs)

2) If `float` computations are faster than `double` computations (sqrt/divide on some processors)

3) If your computation is vectorizable, and your vector unit can operate on more `float` elements in parallel than on `double` elements (most current SIMD vector processors).

For OpenCV, I'd expect *all* of these to be relevant to some degree.